# How to model the Cable composites in Mujoco Physics Simulation engine

Tags: ros, ros2, manipulator, physics-engine, mujoco

How to name the cable composite in mujoco, also how to add equality constraint to the end of the cable with another body ?

Answer (score 0):

You'd get more engagement if you ask this question on MuJoCo's GitHub page (but first, search for the answer there -- the community is active and the resolved issues are a treasure trove of tips and tricks).